# Three task batch files for my game servers

Tags: list, batch-file, logging, delete-file

I need 3 different batch files for 3 different tasks:

-log the output of HldsUpdateTool.exe console, so far I don't see what's going on but I managed this:

```
@echo off
echo Updating...
call :Logit>>log.txt 2>&1
exit /b 0
:Logit
hldsupdatetool.exe -command update -game "Counter-Strike Source" -dir "Source 2007 Dedicated Server" -verify_all -retry
start notepad log.txt
```

-clean this log to get a files and folders list; the log will look like this:

```
Checking bootstrapper version ...
Updating Installation
Determining which depot(s) to install/update...
5 depot(s) will be installed/updated
  0:30 Checking local files and building download list for depot 242 'Counter-Strike Source Shared' version 126
  0:30     Connecting content server session for version 126
  0:31     [80.239.194.146:27030] Connecting...
  0:31     [80.239.194.146:27030] Connection established; handshaking...
  0:31     [80.239.194.146:27030] Sending login message...
  0:31     Fetching version 126 manifest
  0:41     Reading version 126 checksum table
  0:54     Calculating download size and verifying checksums
  0:54         Checking...: /
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\bin
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\cfg
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\classes
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\maps
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\maps\graphs
  0:54         Checking...: cstrike\maps\soundcache
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials\brick
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials\buildings
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials\carpet
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials\composite
  0:57         Checking...: cstrike\materials\concrete
  0:58         Checking...: cstrike\materials\console
etc... later on files do not have extensions!
```

-clean the server folder from any files or folders not listed!

I did search around for 2 days but this is as far as I can go by myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,I'm a definitely newer to batch :)
As for the 2nd question:
 -clean this log to get a files and folders list; the log will look like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %G in ('findstr /i /c:"checking..." log.txt')do echo %G>>_.log
```

May it works for you.

**Update:**
I download your log.txt and test immediately,this is the result(file names _.log):

```
/
cstrike
cstrike\bin
cstrike\cfg
cstrike\classes
cstrike\maps
cstrike\maps\graphs
cstrike\maps\soundcache
cstrike\materials
cstrike\materials\brick
cstrike\materials\buildings
cstrike\materials\carpet
cstrike\materials\composite
cstrike\materials\concrete
cstrike\materials\console
cstrike\materials\cs_assault
cstrike\materials\cs_havana
cstrike\materials\cs_italy
cstrike\materials\cstrike
cstrike\materials\de_aztec
cstrike\materials\de_cbble
cstrike\materials\de_chateau
cstrike\materials\de_dust
cstrike\materials\de_nuke
cstrike\materials\de_piranesi
cstrike\materials\de_prodigy
cstrike\materials\de_tides
cstrike\materials\de_train
cstrike\materials\decals
cstrike\materials\decals\concrete
cstrike\materials\decals\metal
cstrike\materials\decals\wood
...
```

Maybe i misunderstood your meaning?

**Update again**

As for 3rd question

```
@echo off
set /p origin=Where is the original folder?(Type absoulute path directly.)
echo origin: %origin%
set /p destin=Where can i put file temporarily(Type absoulute path directly.)
echo destination :%destin%


for /f %%G in (_.log) do (
if "%%G"=="/" (
    echo.
) else ( 
    xcopy %origin%\%%G %destin%\%%G /H /K /R /E /D /I /Y 
))

rm -rf %origin%
set /p origin=What is the name of original folder?(Type name)
rename %destin% %origin%
```

May it help you!

**Update the third time :)**

Because the first edition maybe little confusing for  you.Sorry for my lacking of ability ti code well.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set MAXNUM=100

set /p origin=Where is the original folder?(Type absoulute path directly.)
echo origin: %origin%
set backup_origin=%origin%

for /L %%H in (1,1,%MAXNUM%) do (
for /F "delims=\" %%G in ("!origin!") do (
set name=%%G
set origin=!origin:%%G\=!
))
set father=!backup_origin:\%name%=!

xcopy !father!\!name! !father!\backup_!name! /H /K /R /E /D /I /Y
::copy files
rm -rf !father!\!name!
::delete origin
rename !father!\backup_!name! !name!
::rename the new folder using the old's name
```

if your files are in such an format `C:\template\example\cstrike\materials\brick`,you should just type `c:\template\example`,which includes `\hl2` `\cstrike` and so on.
I work on Win7,which you may not.So I recommend you to adjust my batch file to your OS.Before running ,check that you have `xcopy`,`rm`,`rename` working for you.T

Comment: @AirMax95s May I have a look at your log file outputted in 1st question

Comment: @AirMax95s I update the answer because i can't format the comment well.

Comment: I'm getting: "checking..." was unexpected at this time." and nothing is created, am I doing something wrong? :/

Comment: Maybe you should check the path because I used relative path in this command?

Comment: OK I got it working by replacing %G with %%G in the 1st one :)
As for the other one I get a lot of "Invalid number of parameters" and "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AirMax95s I update it agian :) Maybe i'm stubborn.You don't have rm? You may not work on Win OS? OK,you can just the code according to the function I listed above in my answer,

Comment: No problem. I'm really happy now .

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten that to

```
@echo off
hldsupdatetool.exe -command update -game "Counter-Strike Source" -dir "Source 2007 Dedicated Server" -verify_all -retry >Log.txt
start notepad Log.txt
```

The problem with the files not showing extensions will be down to the program you are running, all the batch does is call the exe and redirect the output.

Comment: Probably the `start notepad log.txt` line should be added at the end. Anyway, what was that about file extensions not showing? The OP doesn't seem to mention any issues with them. What am I missing?

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah I guess so, the last bit is about the OP's comment on the output of the app - `etc... later on files do not have extensions!`

Comment: Ah, how could I miss that? I guess I just dismissed everything after `etc.` on that line as unimportant. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I almost missed it too :)

Comment: Shorter and more accurate but same effect as what I already have unfortunately. I would like to see the output directly in the console as it writes it to the log. As for the rest I still need help :(

Comment: I'm really not sure what your trying to do, could you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Sure, now it logs the output in a text file like I wanted but I'd like to be able to see the stream of info as it updates in the cmd window instead of just "Updating..."
Thank you :)